# Google Street View Premium Plan API - API server rejects your request

Tags: google-street-view

I'm trying to switch from basic Google Street View API to Premium. As such, when I'm using:
(space after https is added because I can't post more than two links in the post)

https:/ /maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=40.720032,-73.988354&size=400x400&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=MY_PREMIUM_API_KEY

I get an image with a Google watermark, which does not scale further than 640x640, same as when using a basic API key.
Okay, to use the advantages of Premium GSV API, I also need to make a digital signature. I've generated a secret key and signed my url (with dropped domain, as said in the tutorial) using python code from there: https:/ /github.com/googlemaps/url-signing/blob/gh-pages/urlsigner.py - it generates just the same signature as one on the Google website: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key?hl=en_GB#premium-key

Finally, I add the signature to the URL:

(space after https is added because I can't post more than two links in the post)

https:/ /maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=40.720032,-73.988354&size=400x400&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=MY_PREMIUM_API_KEY&signature=MY_BASE64_SIGNATURE

However, this is what I get in return instead of an image:
"The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=_"

It cannot be that API project is not activated, as basic API with this project & Premium key works. Any ideas, why does it happen and Premium image download doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a purely technical problem, the quotas were exceeded.